# How to split multiple sentences and encase them in double quotes based on a period in python

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns.  In my pattern column, there are multiple sentences that end with a period.  I need each sentence to have a have a double quote around it.

Below is the orignal text

| patterns |
| --- |
| Keep related supplies in the same area., Make an effort to clean a dedicated workspace after every session., Place loose supplies in large, clearly visible containers., Use clotheslines and clips to hang sketches, photos, and reference material., Use every inch of the room for storage, especially vertical space., Use chalkboard paint to make space for drafting ideas right on the walls., Purchase a label maker to make your organization strategy semi permanent., Make a habit of throwing out old, excess, or useless stuff each month. |

I need the results to be:

| patterns |
| --- |
| "Keep related supplies in the same area.", "Make an effort to clean a dedicated workspace after every session.", "Place loose supplies in large, clearly visible containers.", "Use clotheslines and clips to hang sketches, photos, and reference material.", "Use every inch of the room for storage, especially vertical space.", "Use chalkboard paint to make space for drafting ideas right on the walls.", "Purchase a label maker to make your organization strategy semi permanent.", "Make a habit of throwing out old, excess, or useless stuff each month." |
|  |

What is did already,

```
df['patterns'] = df['patterns'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Do you want a list of strings in the dataframe column? Or a single string with quotes and commas added?

Comment: Same question as above - your data implies you have a .txt file (possibly .csv?) but your code implies that you've read it into a data frame. You could treat the data (paragraph) as one big string and just replace every instance of ., with ."," then prepend and append " to the start and end.

Comment: `re.split()` doesn't add anything, it uses the regexp as the delimiter to split the input. Since there aren't any quotes in the input, your pattern never matches anything.

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? Edit the question. Also, the dataframe isn't really anything to do with the problem is it? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: It is a csv file.

Comment: Use `.str.replace()` to replace characters or patterns in a df column.

Comment: Because I tried it.   It did not give me the results I wanted, which is the results I need above.

Comment: It looks like `.,` is the delimiter between the sentences, not `."`.

Comment: How would I use replace, and please show me it works.

Comment: How will I get the results I want.  I will use anything.

Comment: I need each sentence to have double quotes around the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
df["patterns"] = (
    df["patterns"]
    .str.findall(r"[A-Z].*?(?=,\s*[A-Z]|\Z)")
    .apply(lambda s: ", ".join(map(lambda s: f'"{s}"', s)))
)
```

Prints:

| patterns |
| --- |
| "Keep related supplies in the same area.", "Make an effort to clean a dedicated workspace after every session.", "Place loose supplies in large, clearly visible containers.", "Use clotheslines and clips to hang sketches, photos, and reference material.", "Use every inch of the room for storage, especially vertical space.", "Use chalkboard paint to make space for drafting ideas right on the walls.", "Purchase a label maker to make your organization strategy semi permanent.", "Make a habit of throwing out old, excess, or useless stuff each month." |

Comment: IT WORKED.  I tried almost everything.  You are the best.  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU.  You are awesome.

Comment: Can you please explain the code, so I can learn want you did.

Comment: @NaeemahSmall Perhaps this site will explain it better: https://regex101.com/r/iVfbxz/1  Basically, I use regular expression to match all sentences (sentence is here defined as uppercase letter following any letters until there is `,` and another uppercase letter in front, or end of the string)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['patterns'] = df['patterns'].str.replace(r'(.*?\.)(,|$)', r'"\1"\2', regex=True)
```

`(.*?\.)(,|$)` matches everything up to a `.` followed by either `,` or the end of the input. In the replacement it puts `"` around the part up to the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on `'., '` to get a list of sentences:

```
>>> text = "abc, def., ghi jkl., mno, pqr., stu vwx."

>>> sentences = text.split("., ")

>>> sentences
['abc, def', 'ghi jkl', 'mno, pqr', 'stu vwx']
```

Then join new strings together made of quoted sentences:

```
>>> ", ".join(f'"{sentence}."' for sentence in sentences)
'"abc, def.", "ghi jkl.", "mno, pqr.", "stu vwx."'
```